# Python, неправильно работает каскад циклов for, в чем ошибка?

Tags: python, циклы, numpy

Мой цикл должен накидать суммы отрицательных и положительных чисел в P[0], затем в P[1], P[2]... и так далее. Но почему то он одновременно кидает во все P (то есть одновременно в P[0], P[1], P[2]). В чем моя ошибка ведь кажется логически все верно.

```
С = [array([[ 2.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  2., -1.],
   [ 0., -1.,  2.]]), array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 2., -1.,  0.],
   [-1.,  2.,  0.]]), array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
   [-1.,  0., -0.],
   [ 2.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0., -0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]), array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
   [-0.,  0.,  2.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  2.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  2., -1.],
   [ 1.,  2., -1.]]), array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 2., -1.,  0.], ....

P = [[0, 0]] * len(C)

for i in range(len(C)):
    for x in range(3):
        for y in range(3):
            if C[i][x][y] >= 0:
                P[i][0] += C[i][x][y]
            if C[i][x][y] < 0:
                P[i][1] += C[i][x][y]
print(P)
>>>
[[687.0, -233.0], [687.0, -233.0], [687.0, -233.0], [687.0, -233.0]...
```

Для тех кто не понял - элементы списка P должны иметь разные значения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неправильно создаете список списков. 
Если делать умножением обычного списка `python`, то вы просто дублируете ссылку на исходный массив:

```
a = [[0, 0]]*2

for i in a:
    print(id(i))

82607176
82607176
```

То есть, присвоение значения любому из подсписков, автоматический присваивает это же значение его копиям.

Воспользуйтесь `numpy.zeros()`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((2, 2))
for i in a:
    print(id(i))

93033856
93034336
```

Answer (score 4):

Без использования numpy можно сделать так:

```
P = [[0,0] for x in range(len(C))]
```